# Wendler's routine, should I adjust? (KG)

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, strength, strength-training

I am doing Wendler's routine, and am still in my first mesocycle.

I hadn't progressed on other routines for six months, doing them properly, such as Stronglifts, mad cow, greyskull and a few others, I am clearly progressing now, but I feel like my set that is meant to be my one rep max being done for 15 reps is ridiculous. Especially considering I am meant to do another of these one rep max things in ~26 days at only 5 kg heavier than what I can already do for 15 reps.

> TL:DR: I am doing really well on Wendler, should I increase the weights even though it is my first cycle?

Attached is my current progress(In KG):

[image]

Note, the final set in Wendler is as many reps as possible, the number of reps achieved is in blue for each workout.

As you can see, I am gaining reps on the final set while increasing the weight, which means it is likely too easy for me(?), and am thus unsure what to do. Following the routine properly I would be doing 120kg as my 1 rep max on Mon 14th of July, which is only 5kg heavier than I did 15 reps for in one set yesterday(16th of June). I feel like I could easily do 13ish reps for 120 already.

What do I do? Apparently I should not change his routine until the fourth cycle atleast, but this seems like a bad idea.

Note 2: I am following every aspect of the conventional routine, including 3x5 LS AMRAP, 3x3 LS AMRAP, 1x5 1x3 1x1 LS AMRAP.

Sorry for long post.

Comment: (Assuming we're talking basic 5/3/1 here) It seems you started _way_ too light. How did you determine your starting weight?

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla It just took a percentage of my known one rep max's. They were(with good form), 132 squat, 101 bench, 122 deadlift, 69 OHP.

All in KG.

Comment: hm... then you're still progressing quite fast. Maybe too fast to cater to 5/3/1's monthly progression. As you seem to be able to progress weekly you're essentially slowing down to fit the routine. I'd rather have a routine that fits me, than the other way around, but that's a philosophical debate, as 'slow and steady' has it's own merits. If you're unhappy, though, maybe try a routine with weekly progression. The one thing I wouldn't do is tampering with 5/3/1, as it's quite specific and easy to mess up.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla The thing was, I was not progressing on greyskull, madcows, stronglifts or any routine I made for myself. But doing Wendlers I seem to be progressing way too fast, and I feel as though I will end up training at 20 reps soon which seems ridiculous.

Comment: Okay, that's weird. Could it be due to fewer auxilliary exercises maybe? What template are you using for 5/3/1? Triumvirate, Big But Boring etc?

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I suppose this, without boring but big http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance/how_to_build_pure_strength

Comment: Hm, okay, no clue why 5/3/1 works so much better than other programms for you then. I did answer your other question (regarding increasing weight), though, which hopefully might have some insights for this question, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, likely too easy for you...but it's working, right?  Strength training is usually conducted with long-term goals in mind.  You are progressing nicely, even if the weight feels too light.  Work on nailing down your form during this time, because if you stick with it, you will be moving large weights down the line, and probably will look back on this time with amusement, when every deadlift didn't make your eyes feel like they are popping out of your head.

Also, imporatant considerations:

1. Are you eating better?
2. Are you sleeping better?
3. Added any supplementation? (Wendler has quite the supplementation regime for beyond 5/3/1.)

From my experience, getting at least 8hrs of uninterupted sleep and eating like you want it are the keys to moving the weight. If you improved upon these two variables, that could well explain your sudden onset of herculean strength.

Best of luck.